# Does a file upload take up one of the worker processes in passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm not sure if this question is passenger specific.

Say I have a server with `passenger_max_instances_per_app 4;` and I have 4 people simultaneously uploading a huge file to the app.

In this situation, would a simple 5th GET request have to wait for those 4 uploads, because the passenger instances are busy?
Or are the passenger processes free until an upload is actually complete and the request gets sent to the rails app?

In other words, does Nginx wait for the full post to be complete before sending the request to the appropriate passenger instance?

Answer (score 0):

Most servers will drop the request after 30 seconds, so having many people uploading a file to your server would stack up and time out if it has to wait for other people uploading files.

If you are storing your objects in S3 look into [uploading the files from the browser directly to your S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

This is a good solution if you have a small app but will require people to upload big files.